# How to I re-enable the ability to select an element in ie and firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used the following script to disable the highlighting of script on a table...

```
function disableSelection(target) {
    if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") //IE route
        target.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
    else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") //Firefox route
        target.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
    else //All other route (ie: Opera)
        target.onmousedown = function () { return false; };
    target.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

I want to be able to reverse the effects of the above method so that when a user clicks on an input in a td they can select all the text using the jQuery.select() method.

I dont really understand how to reverse the effects when I tried...

```
function enableSelection(target) {
    if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") //IE route
        target.onselectstart = function () { return true; };
    else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") //Firefox route
        target.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
    else //All other route (ie: Opera)
        target.onmousedown = function () { return false; };
    target.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

It doesnt work, I get object not found errors in IE. Hope someone can help this is for an important bit of work that I have to get done for the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work in IE.  Are you sure it's not related to some other error?

Here is a test page that works for me in IE 9:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body> 
    <div id="test">
        test test
        test test
        <br />
        test test
    </div>
    <button onclick="disableSelection(document.getElementById('test'))" value="off">off</button>
    <button onclick="enableSelection(document.getElementById('test'))" value="on">on</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function enableSelection(target) {
            if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") //IE route
                target.onselectstart = function () { return true; };
            else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") //Firefox route
                target.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
            else //All other route (ie: Opera)
                target.onmousedown = function () { return false; };
            target.style.cursor = "default";
        }

        function disableSelection(target) {
            if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") //IE route
                target.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
            else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") //Firefox route
                target.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
            else //All other route (ie: Opera)
                target.onmousedown = function () { return false; };
            target.style.cursor = "default";
        }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (only tested in chrome)

```
function enableSelection(target) {
    //For IE This code will work
    if(typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") {
        target.onselectstart = function() {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //For Firefox This code will work
    else if(typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") {
        target.style.MozUserSelect = "all";
    }

    //All other  (ie: Opera) This code will work
    else {
        target.onmousedown = function() {
            return true;
        }
    target.style.cursor = "default";
    }
}
```